# How to redirect to custom cms in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, event-observer, magento2.4.2

When quote table or customer session destroy page is rediecting to cart empty page.
I want to redirect to my custom cms page.
how to do that?

I used below code but not working:

```
$this->customerSession->destroy();
            $customRedirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('custom-cms-page');
            $this->actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        // then in last redirect
            $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl);

            return $this;
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
protected $responseFactory;
protected $url;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ...
) {
    $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    $customRedirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('custom-cms-pagee'); //Get url of cms page
    $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse(); 
}
```

Comment: I tried above code but not working

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create events.xml file    Mital/RedirectCustomPage/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index">
        <observer name="validate_cart" instance="Mital\RedirectCustomPage\Observer\ValidateCartObserver" />
    </event>    
</config>
```

> 2. Create obeserver   Mital\RedirectCustomPage\Observer\ValidateCartObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Mital\RedirectCustomPage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ValidateCartObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    
    /**
     * @var RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param RedirectInterface $redirect
     * @param CustomerCart $cart
     */
    public function __construct(        
        RedirectInterface $redirect,        
        CustomerCart $cart
    ) {        
        $this->redirect = $redirect;        
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }
   
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {  
        $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        if (!$quote->getId()) {               
            $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'custom-cms-page'); //Add your custom url
        }        
    }   
}
```

Comment: above code is not working still it is redirecting to empty cart

Comment: It should work. please check is there any other module that creates an issue. I tried this code in my setup and it works well :)

Comment: Which event are you using?

Comment: I'm using this event                                                                                                   
 <event name="sales_order_place_before">
        <observer name="coupon_checkout_validate" instance="Test\Module\Observer\webapi_rest\Couponcheck" />
    </event>

Comment: You are using the wrong event. Try controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index event. which i mentioned above.

Comment: is the redirection not work in this   sales_order_place_before event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126760/discussion-between-mital-shah-and-venkata-prasad).